# Can confirmatory factor analysis be used to test the components form a principal components analysis?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor

I have completed a PCA on a data set in study 1 (using the `principal` function in the `psych` package in R) and now I am wondering if I can complete a CFA on my study 2 data to confirm my results from study 1 are reliable.

Is this the acceptable method or is there a different analysis that I should complete for my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the factor model you want to run? The principal components themselves do not automatically provide a factor model.

Have you discarded some of them? (There are as many principal components as there are variables, but in a factor model, there are fewer factors than variables.)

Have you then rotated them? (Unrotated principal components do not yield any interesting structure, as all variables are explained by all components. Such a structure is not impossible but unusual.)

If so, you have essentially done exploratory factor analysis. You have presumably identified some tentative factor structure (identified which latent factors explain which variables) which you can then analyze further using CFA.

Comment: Thank you for responding so fast! 

I ran a PCA using the psych::principal() function in R on a 13-item questionnaire. The final solution (with varimax rotation) reached simple structure, with 1 item being removed (split-loaded) and 3 components in total.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I have to tag you, I am very new to stackexchange...

Comment: @AnaRuiz, great, so you have done EFA and now want to move on to CFA. As long as you have new data for CFA, you can go ahead. But if you were to use the exact same dataset first for EFA and then for CFA, you could not trust the results of CFA. (To give an analogy, this would be like first estimating the mean of a sample and then setting the estimated value as the null hypothesis and testing it; you would never ever reject it.) You do not have to tag me if you are commenting under my answer. Otherwise, you need to tag me like this: [at]RichardHardy, just like I tagged you above.

Comment: @AnaRuiz, to get more familiar with how Cross Validated works, I recommend taking a quick and painless tour [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: This makes sense--thank you! I do have a new data set for the CRA. I was just unsure of whether there would be a different analysis if my original exploratory analysis was technically a PCA rather than a EFA, but I take it that those two can be synonymous in this instance. If you have any recommendations for guides on completing a CFA in R, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @AnaRuiz, I do not have recommendations beyond what I could Google. Yes, PCA is one way of extracting factors; PCA extract PCs first, then some are discarded while the rest get rotated to yield the fitted factors.

Comment: ok. Thank you for all your help!